# The letter A appears an even number of times. How many different sequences could Dr. Lizardo have written down?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recursion

> Dr. Lizardo writes down a sequence of $n$ letters, where each letter is A, B, or C, and the letter A appears an even number of times. How many different sequences could Dr. Lizardo have written down?

---

**What I have tried so far**

The last letter is predefined in terms of "A or not" based on the first $n-1$ letters. If there are an odd number of As so far, the last one has to be A, otherwise, B or C. Therefore, there are $3^{n-1}$ ways to write the first $n-1$ letters. However, the last letter can either have 1 choice or 2 choices.

I am thinking maybe we need to do $S_n = 3^{n-1} + S_{n-1}$. However, I need a closed form, not a recurrance. How can I do this?

Thank you!

---

Note: $S_n = 3^{n-1} + S_{n-1}$ seems to be working for the first few values of $n$ (I tested through $n=4$), so finding a closed form of that recurrance would work as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the number of strings at size $n$ that is constructed from ${a,b,c,d}$ and there is an even num of $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326815/what-is-the-number-of-strings-at-size-n-that-is-constructed-from-a-b-c-d-a) See "More generally" in the accepted answer. The number of strings of length $n$ over a $k$-letter alphabet with a certain letter required to appear an even number of times is $$\frac{k^n+(k-2)^n}2.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider two cases.

**Case 1.** The sequence is all C's. There is just one such sequence, and it has an even number of A's, namely zero.

**Case 2.** The sequence is not all C's. There are $3^n-1$ such sequences, and exactly half of them, or $\frac{3^n-1}2$, have an even number of A's. To see this, look at the leftmost letter in the sequence that's not a C; toggling it between A and B, we see that there's a one-to-one correspondence between sequences with an even and an odd number of A's.

Combining the results from Case 1 and Case 2, we get a grand total of
$$1+\frac{3^n-1}2=\frac{3^n+1}2.$$

More generally, over an alphabet of $k$ letters, the number of sequences of length $n$ in which a certain letter appears an even number of times is
$$(k-2)^n+\frac{k^n-(k-2)^n}2=\frac{k^n+(k-2)^n}2;$$
see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326815/what-is-the-number-of-strings-at-size-n-that-is-constructed-from-a-b-c-d-a).

Answer (score 4):

Setting $S_0 = 1$ (the empty sequence definitely has an even number of 'A's) and then defining $S_n = 3^{n-1} + S_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 1$ gives
$$S_n = S_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{n=1}3^k = 1 + \frac{1-3^n}{1-3} = \frac{3^n+1}{2}$$

where we have used the formula for the finite geometric series
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ar^k = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$

---

Another way to see this is to use generating functions:
$$P(x,y,z) = (x+y+z)^n = \sum_{\substack{i,j,k \geq 0 \\ i+j+k=n}} S(i,j,k)x^iy^jz^k$$
is the generating function for the number of sequences $S(i,j,k)$ with $i$ 'A's, $j$ 'B's, and $k$ 'C's.  We want to find $$\sum_{\substack{i,j,k \geq 0 \\ i+j+k=n \\ 2|i}} S(i,j,k)$$

To impose the assumption that $i$ is even, we take the even part with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{P(x,y,z) + P(-x,y,z)}{2} = \sum_{\substack{i,j,k \geq 0 \\ i+j+k=n \\ 2|i}} S(i,j,k)x^iy^jz^k$$

and then we just evaluate at $x=y=z=1$:
$$\frac{(1+1+1)^n + (-1+1+1)^n}{2} = \sum_{\substack{i,j,k \geq 0 \\ i+j+k=n \\ 2|i}} S(i,j,k)$$

which we note simplifies once again to $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

Good analysis, but a closed form requires that you get *down in the mud*.
Note : possible exception is if someone can provide a more elegant computation than my **kludgy** approach.

Let $c = \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor.$

That is $c$ is the largest integer such that $2c \leq n$.

Then, you want

$$\sum_{k=0}^c f(k)$$,

where $f(k)$ is the exact # of ways of having $2k$ A's in the sequence.

There are $\binom{n}{2k}$ ways of distributing the $2k$ A's.

There are $2^{(n-2k)}$ ways of choosing B or C for the $(n - 2k)$ other slots.

Therefore,

$$f(k) = \binom{n}{2k} \times 2^{(n-2k)}.$$

It is unclear to me whether the summation can be expressed in a simpler fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Here we show the equality of two already given answers. The number $S_n$ is given by

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(3^n+1\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k}2^{n-2k}\qquad\qquad  n\geq 0}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

The following is valid
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}&=(1+x)^n\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}&=(1-x)^n\\
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}&=\frac{1}{2}\left((1+x)^n+(1-x)^n\right)\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k}2^{n-2k}}
> &=2^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k}\\
> &=2^n\,\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right)\\
> &=2^n\,\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}\left(3^n+1\right)}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

Comment: +1 Very timely, clear, and elegant exposition.

Comment: @user2661923: Many thanks for your nice comment. Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit more of a linear algebra proof which is probably not what you are seeking but I'd still like to share it anyways. Define two sequences $a_n$ being the number of length-$n$ sequences with even number of As and $b_n$ being the number of length-$n$ sequences with odd number of As. Clearly $a_0 = 1$ and $b_0 = 0$

Notice that the if you have an length-$(n-1)$ sequences with even number of As: there are two ways to add one character (either B or C) so that the new length-$n$ sequence has even As and there is one way to add one character (A) so that the new length-$n$ sequence has odd As.

Similarly if you have an length-$(n-1)$ sequences with odd number of As: there is one way to add one character (A) so that the new length-$n$ sequence has even As and there are two ways to add one character (B or C) so that the new length-$n$ sequence has odd As.

From here we can define a recurrence relation in terms of matrices
$$ \left( \begin{matrix} a_{n} \\ b_{n} \end{matrix} \right) =
\left( \begin{matrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{matrix} \right)
\left( \begin{matrix} a_{n-1} \\ b_{n-1} \end{matrix} \right) =
\left( \begin{matrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{matrix} \right)^n
\left( \begin{matrix} a_{0} \\ b_{0} \end{matrix} \right)$$

If we diagonalize this matrix we get
$$ \left( \begin{matrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{matrix} \right) =
\left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)
\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{matrix} \right)
\frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} a_{n} \\ b_{n} \end{matrix} \right) =
\left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)
\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3^n \end{matrix} \right)
\frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)
\left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right) = 
\frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{matrix} 3^n+1 \\ 3^n-1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

thus $a_n = \frac{3^n+1}{2}$